# How can I make a linear swept face using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I make a linear swept face?

I wrote following code.

```
      // profile
      var pts = [
        new THREE.Vector2(0, 0), 
        new THREE.Vector2(10, 0), 
        new THREE.Vector2(10, 10), 
        new THREE.Vector2(20, 10), 
        new THREE.Vector2(20, 20),
      ];
      var profile = new THREE.Shape(pts);
      // path
      var path = new THREE.LineCurve3(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(30, 0, 30));
      var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(profile , { steps: 1, bevelEnabled: false, extrudePath: path });
      var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xff8000, wireframe: false });
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(mesh);
```

And I got a result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0lQy.jpg

But it is not what my needing. My hope is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcDgw.jpg

What is wrong?

Comment: Thanks! Does your comment means no **STANDARD/GENERAL** way to make a swept face? In that case, I will try to make it by myself.

Comment: Check out [`THREE.ExtrudeGeometry`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/ExtrudeGeometry).

Answer (score 0):

There is [`THREE.ExtrudeGeometry`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/ExtrudeGeometry) for this.

There are several examples on **[the three.js examples page](http://threejs.org/examples/)**:

- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes
- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2
- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_splines

Comment: I missed the keyword 'extrude'!
Thanks!

Comment: @kenta, maybe you can accept the answer to close this question?